# Size of particle so small that it covers large volume?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

An electron's "cloud" covers more volume than a proton does due to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Δmv*Δx > h

an electron has less mass than a proton, so its position is less determinate.

What if a particle, or string is much smaller? Could something like that have a propabilistic volume that permeates huge expanses of space (maybe even lightyears)?

Comment: You are confounding "small" with "light" and "well determined momentum". One does not follow from the other.

Comment: And that's not even borderline true in a relativistic world where everything depends on the energy-momentum and not on the rest mass... Now, elementary particles are not associated with any length scale, their "size" is not defined because what you call "a particle" is actually a quantum of a field which is defined over a continuum (at least in conventional QFT).

Comment: @CuriousOne the QFT view is a valid but theoretical one: on par with virtual particles, an extremely useful mathematical framework but only measurable through real particles  and confusing to newbies, imo.

Comment: @annav: without new evidence I have to stick to what I know. QFT works and its definition of quanta (it does not talk about particles) makes this pretty trivial to deal with. I don't believe a "newbie" is served by pretending that we are dealing with particles the way they are being understood by layman. The shiny little billiard ball set got lost in physics some 80 years ago, and we should not pretend that it's still on the table. I like your answer, by the way.

Comment: @CuriousOne Theoretically inclined people tend to think that way, I know, but "works" has to be based on measurements and believe me, the only measurements in particle physics are on "particles", widely defined, but still entities in space and time with specific numbers measured on them.

Comment: @annav: curiously I am an experimentalist who has worked on high energy physics particle detectors, and I never thought that I was measuring actual particles. I was always pretty certain that I was supposed to be measuring changes in quantum numbers like charge, spin, lepton number etc..  I have certainly not met a theoretical physicist or a phenomenologist who told me to stop measuring quanta and to start measuring particles, instead, but I am sure they are out there. There is always somebody who doesn't quite understand what they are doing.

Comment: @CuriousOne I started by bubble chamber pictures, then Aleph with its TPC . The particle framework is very visual. I can see that working with detectors the number of proxies is such that one can get familiar with a QFT format , but it is a hard one/incomprehensible  for the laymen, and also multiplies to the extreme the confusion with virtual and real.

Comment: @annav: By the time we had bubble chambers (1952) we already knew that we were dealing with quanta and not with particles. Admittedly, depending on the quality of the teachers this may not be expressed properly in class and students are left to wander the earth with the wrong mental image for far too long. In some ways I think it helps to be an experimentalist, at least I am aware that in a bubble chamber I am looking at bubbles and in an Argon calorimeter I am measuring the charges of ions and electrons and not actual particle energy. All of these devices are only giving us secondary effects.

Comment: @CuriousOne well, we have a different pov. I do not believe that mathematics creates the world ( the platonic ideal ). I believe that mathematical models describe the world, successive ones more and more successfully. Even though second quantization is amazing, it is still a mathematical model going through levels of proxies (nested secondary effects) to reach the data we can record .It still depends for predictions on functions that are the solutions of the elementary quantum mechanical potential problems, otherwise no numbers would come out to be measured and verified.  Happy holidays.

Comment: @annav: There is not a single experiment in physics that suggests that particles exist. Particles are a philosophical concept that derives from the idea of atomism, that one can divide the world into parts that are smaller and smaller, but essentially identical in their properties to the whole except in size. We now know that that was a historic misconception. Why should we stick to it? Mathematics has nothing to do with any of this. Either a concept works or it doesn't and I can't see how particles can be made to work.

Comment: @CuriousOne  in that sense also we do not exist for each other either. Maybe we are figments of each other's imaginations. The concept of "quantum mechanical entity" works fine for all the experimental data up to now. For me, the rest is mathematics on par with virtual particles in the Feynman diagrams. This picture is not a philosophical concept: http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/27925

Comment: @annav: I am not a solipsist. I am also not into faith. I simply try to take the things that the universe presents to me at face value. You exist. I exist. A picture generated by bubbles is a picture generated by bubbles. That's no different from a clock is a clock and a ruler is a ruler. A clock is not time. A ruler is not space. Bubbles are not particles.  What's wrong with that? It's just Plato's cave shadows taken seriously. The man had a point, he merely failed when he claimed that philosophers (or physicist) could climb out of the cave. We can't because the cave is our mind.

Answer (score 1):

> An electron's "cloud" covers more volume than a proton does due to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.
>
> Δmv*Δx > h

The m in the expression is not a variable. It is a fixed number, so protons and electrons behave the same way at a given momentum. It is the solutions of the quantum mechanical equations of the interaction between an electron and a proton that gives the bound stated that define the orbitals for the electron around the proton. The average size belongs to the whole atom, not the electron. Those solutions have a probability of zero at macroscopic distances, 10 to a very large negative exponent.

> an electron has less mass than a proton, so its position is less determinate

this is false for equal momenta, which is what enters the heisenberg uncertainty.

> What if a particle, or string is much smaller? Could something like that have a propabilistic volume that permeates huge expanses of space (maybe even lightyears)?

See above. The mass is not a variable, and it is the momentum that enters.

And again, the mathematical solutions of the system will show that the probabilities will be infinitesimally  small the larger the distances from the source of the potential.

Answer (score 0):

According to quantum mechanics, every probability wave (including electron's) extends
throughout all of space, throughout the entire universe. But the probability of finding your electron at large distances will be very close to zero.

---

Reference: The Fabric of Cosmos-Space, Time, and the Texture of Reality, by Brian Greene.